# What is the time complexity of nested for loop within a while loop in BFS algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, breadth-first-search, undirected-graph

So, I've written an algorithm that returns list of nodes connected to a give node and within a max number of hops in an undirected graph.

Note: Undirected graph means if A is connected to B then B is also connected to A.

Basically, let's say edges are as follows:

```
"A", "B"
"A", "C"
"B", "D"
"C", "E"
"E", "F"
"E", "G"
```

Edges are stored in a hashmap like `map[string][]string` as follows:

```
{"A": ["B","C"]}, {"B", ["A", "D"]}... goes on.
```

and `FindNodes("C", 2)` returns `["A", "B", "E", "F", "G"]`
or  `FindNodes("A", 1)` returns `["B", "C"]`.

I applied BFS algorithm as follows:

- Add the first node to queue.
- Creates `while` loop until **queue** becomes nil or **counter** becomes same as **maxHop**.
- Get the number of nodes in the queue.
- Poll the node and mark it as **currentNode**
- Create for loop according to the number of queue.
- And then create another loop to get neighbours of **currentNode**

So, the algorithm is as follows. And I'm quite confused about the time complexity of the algorithm. Any recommendations?

I don't it looks like an algorithm that has `O(n^3)` time complexity. What's the right way to reach correct time complexity? Because every for loop and the while loop depends on some condition (as it should be) but what's the time complexity?

```
// FindNodes returns list of nodes connected to a given node and within a max number of hops
// e.g. "A", 2 -> ["B", "C", "D", "E"]
func (ug *UndirectedGraph) FindNodes(node string, maxHops int) []string {
    // if hop number is 0 then it returns the root, node itself.
    if maxHops == 0 {
        return []string{node}
    }

    result := []string{}
    counter := 0
    queue := Queue{Nodes: []string{}}
    queue.add(node)

    for len(queue.Nodes) != 0 && counter != maxHops {

        cnt := len(queue.Nodes)
        for i := 0; i < cnt; i++ {
            currentNode := queue.poll()
            if _, ok := ug.Visited[currentNode]; ok {
                continue
            }

            ug.Visited[currentNode] = true
            neighbours := ug.Edges[currentNode]
            for _, neighbour := range neighbours {
                if _, ok := ug.Visited[neighbour]; !ok {
                    result = append(result, neighbour)
                    queue.add(neighbour)
                }
            }
        }

        counter += 1
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Maybe checkout https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search. Though you are finding all nodes not just a specific one I think the worst-case complexity is the same.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? So, having a nested loop within a while does not change the time complexity at all. Should I calculate the time complexity of the algorithm as if it's a default bfs algorithm?